# Opentok audio echo Issue

Tags: webrtc, opentok

I use opentok WebRTC js api for both 2.0 and 2.2 to develop. When I follow http://digitaltsai.com/ot/examples/restrictFrameRate.php and enable audio to test it with Mac and Nexus 7. There is an echo issue.

My test environment:

Nexus 7 with Chrome and Firefox, Android 4.4.
Mac OS with Chrome.

But if I test it on other WebRTC demo site (https://apprtc.appspot.com), there is no echo.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks.

Kos

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could be more helpful but I cant reproduce the echo. One problem could be that your nexus 7 was too close to your mac when you are testing the restrictFrameRate. Can you reproduce this consistently? What if you tried http://opentokrtc.com ?